# Ignore held down key press with pdcurses

Tags: c++, pdcurses

```
#include <curses.h>
#include "SourceFiles/generalFunc.h"

int main(){

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    wtimeout(stdscr,0); //NON-BLOCKING IO. getch returns ERR if no input is read.

    int x = 0;
    sleepMilli(3000); //three seconds
    while((x = wgetch(stdscr)) != ERR){
        x = wgetch(stdscr);
        //flushinp();
        waddch(stdscr,x);
        wrefresh(stdscr);
    }

    waddstr(stdscr, " THAT'S ALL FOLKS!");
    wrefresh(stdscr);
    sleepMilli(2000);
    endwin();


}
```

`sleepMilli` is a function that waits for however many milliseconds.

I am writing a program that detects a key press, does some work, waits a certain amount of time `t`, and then detects another key press and does some work, and so on. Of course if `t` is large and the user has held down a key, that key repeats itself in the input buffer, so when the user lets go of the key the program will carry on processing that input buffer until it is done with the repeated key input. That's going to look weird, especially if that repeated key  moves the terminal cursor (it will carry on moving long after the user lets go).

I need a way to read ONE input from the held down key, and then discard the rest. I *thought* that was what `flushinp()` did, but I realised I was wrong. In the above program, if `flushinp()` is commented out, then with input such as:

`cvcvcvcvcvcvcv`

(so I am not holding down a key) The output is:

`cvcvcvcvcvcvcv`

If I hold down the key `c` then the output is:

`cccccccccccccc`

If I uncomment `flushinp()` and do the same two inputs, the outputs are:

`c`

and

`cccccccccccccc`

So `flushinp()` only works for singular key presses, but not repeated key events. Is it possible (on 64-bit Windows) to just read one input from a held down key and discard the rest? I don't want to turn off repeat keys completely, because obviously I want the user to be able to move the cursor continuously by holding down a key.

Comment: Note - Key press events are not a part of C++, but then curses isn't either ... tag problem?.

Comment: In a system I worked on, curses (not pdcurses) and C++ combined with a vxWork provided 'select' to handle serial i/o.  On Linux, the "man select" command description discusses 'file descriptors'.  Should you decide to continue down this path, you will be using C++ to create 'file descriptors' to the user i/o, and call the Linux API "select" to "monitor them, triggering a wait until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation".  'timeouts' of select might prove to be useful.  An example might be labeled "kbhit()" ... google for enlightenment,